# 400 bad PUT request using RTK query and strapi rest api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit, strapi

so am creating a crud app using strapi rest api as my backend end, but am a new react developer and I cant seem to handle put requests to update the api response. it works succesfully in postman but throws a 400 bad request in the app

here is the endpoints of rtk mutation reducer

```
updatePet: builder.mutation({
      query: (payload) => ({
          url: `/pets/${payload.id}`,
          method: 'PUT',
          body: payload,
          headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
          },
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ['Pet'],
    }),
```

the editPetEntry page

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

// mui components
import {
    Typography,
    TextField,
    Box,
    Button,
    Paper
} from '@mui/material';

// mui icons
import { Edit } from '@mui/icons-material';

// custom components
import BottomNav from './BottomNav';

import { useUpdatePetMutation, useGetPetQuery } from '../services/petApi';
import Loader from './Loader';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { usePetContext } from '../petContext';

export default function EditPetEntry() {
    // input data
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [animal, setAnimal] = useState("");
    const [breed, setBreed] = useState("");
    const [age, setAge] = useState("");
    const [location, setLocation] = useState("");
    const [sex, setSex] = useState("");

    // const {petId} = useParams();
    const { petId } = useParams();
    // edit req
    const { data: pet} = useGetPetQuery(petId)
    const [updatePet, { isLoading }] = useUpdatePetMutation();
    const data = JSON.stringify({
        "data": {
            "name": name,
            "animal": animal,
            "breed": breed,
            "age": age,
            "location": location,
            "sex": sex
        }
    });
    const handleEditPet = () => {
        updatePet({ id: petId, data });
    };

    console.log(data);
    console.log(petId);
    console.log(pet);

    return (
        <Box
            component="form"
            sx={{
                '& .MuiTextField-root': { m: 1, width: '50ch' },
                display: 'flex',
                flexDirection: 'column'
            }}
            noValidate
            autoComplete="off"
        >
            <div>
                <Typography variant="h3" gutterBottom component="div">
                    Edit Pet entry
                </Typography>
                <TextField
                    required
                    id="filled-name"
                    label="Name"
                    variant="outlined"
                    onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                />
                <TextField
                    required
                    id="filled-animal"
                    label="Animal"
                    variant="outlined"
                    helperText="Cat, Dog, Bird"
                    onChange={(e) => setAnimal(e.target.value)}
                />
                <TextField
                    required
                    id="filled-breed-input"
                    label="Breed"
                    variant="outlined"
                    onChange={(e) => setBreed(e.target.value)}
                />
                <TextField
                    required
                    id="filled-location-input"
                    label="Location"
                    variant="outlined"
                    onChange={(e) => setLocation(e.target.value)}
                />
                <TextField
                    required
                    id="filled-age"
                    label="Age"
                    type="number"
                    variant="outlined"
                    onChange={(e) => setAge(e.target.value)}
                />
                <TextField
                    required
                    id="sex"
                    label="Sex"
                    helperText="Male, Female"
                    variant="outlined"
                    onChange={(e) => setSex(e.target.value)}
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleEditPet} startIcon={<Edit />}>
                    Edit Pet Entry
                </Button>
                {isLoading && <Loader />}
            </div>
            <Paper sx={{ position: 'fixed', bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0 }} elevation={3}>
                <BottomNav />
            </Paper>
        </Box>
    );
}
```

the error I keep getting

```
{"data":null,"error":{"status":400,"name":"ValidationError","message":"Missing \"data\" payload in the request body","details":{}}}
```

how do I handle it do I can update the details at a particular id, am getting petId from useparams using react router

Answer (score 0):

```
body:{data:payload}
```

In the updatePet mutation

The reason that you passing data as payload, and body should explicitly have data property with all your data in it.

Also you don’t need

```
headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
          },
```

And JSON.stringy it’s all done under the hood for you

Comment: didn't work bro, i just tested the same api url that gave the 400 bad request with postman using the example json put request object on strapi rest api docs and response 200 OK. Could it be that I am not handling the form properly?

Comment: Likely the problem is that you have data.data or something like that.

Comment: Try `updatePet({id:petId, data: {name, animal, breed, animal, age, sex})`

Comment: Then `query: ({id, data}) =>`

Comment: `body: { data }`

Comment: i tried you first solution again, now I get a 204 and 200 OK response but the pets don't change(it doesn't re-render with the updated value) I have already set up tagtypes?

Comment: hey, would you be interested to see the [repo](https://github.com/Keyzcharly/petpound)?

Comment: Yea will take a look tommo